# Coffeescript string interpolation behavior

Tags: string, coffeescript

```
first_name = "Matt"
full_name1 = "#{first_name } Boler"
console.log(full_name1)
```

My understanding is that this is supposed to concatenate the strings and print out

```
Matt Boler
```

to the terminal. Instead, it prints out

```
#{first_name1} Boler
```

What am I missing? This is being done on windows with node.js

Comment: It looks like in the console it's printing out `first_name1` instead of `first_name` from the string? Can you verify whether the string or the output here matches what you have in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine but only when you put string interpolation in double quotes `""` instead of single ones `''`.

Output that you presented is made with string interpolation using single quotes but your code is ok and should output as expected.

```
first_name = "Matt"
single_quotes_name = '#{first_name } Boler'
double_quotes_name = "#{first_name } Boler"

console.log single_quotes_name  # => #{first_name } Boler
console.log double_quotes_name  # => Matt Boler
```

Comment: How so? I did't said that this is useful in anything practical, its just that you have to use double quotes to do string interpolation.

Comment: me no read gud, nevermind! - The example is right but the first sentence is backwards.